# Enzyme: How can I test a component with DOM side-effect?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Say I have a component like so -

```
// @flow

import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';


export default class ReplaceLink extends Component {
  containerRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    const links = 
      Array.from(this.containerRef.current.getElementsByTagName('a'));
    links.forEach(a => a.setAttribute('href', 'dummylink'));
  }

  render = () => <div ref={this.containerRef}>{this.props.children}</div>;
}
```

which replaces href of links placed within it. But even when doing full dom rendering in enzyme, when I do a `wrapper.debug()` to see the result of the render, I still see original links only.

I've tried doing a force `wrapper.update` and using setTimeouts, but it just doesn't reflect the expected link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the best way to test something like this is through the `getDOMNode` method.

1. First, make sure to use `mount` to render the wrapper, so we have a simulated DOM environment to query against.
2. Next, use `wrapper.getDOMNode()` to get the underlying DOM node.
3. Any changes made during the lifecycle methods to the underlying DOM will be reflected in this DOM reference.
4. Use `.querySelector`, or `<insert-dom-query-method>` to make assertions.

   ```
   const wrapper = mount(
     <ReplaceLink> 
       <a href="gogole.com"> Google</a> 
     </ReplaceLink>
   );

   const linkTags = wrapper.getDOMNode().querySelectorAll('a');

   linkTags.forEach(tag => {
     expect(tag.getAttribute('href')).toBe('dummy');
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One of reasons why direct DOM access is discouraged in React is that it makes testing more complicated.

The component can be rendered with skipped `componentDidMount`:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<ReplaceLink/>, { disableLifecycleMethods: true })
```

Then a ref can be mocked and `componentDidMount` can be called manually:

```
const setAttribute = jest.fn();
const getElementsByTagName = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => [{ setAttribute }]);

wrapper.instance().containerRef.current = { getElementsByTagName };
wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
```

Then stubbed DOM functions can be asserted that they were called.